# Replace html tag with new tag content

Tags: javascript, html

The html tag for the page doesn't have lang=en attribute, I'm trying to add it to html tag, below is the code I did it but it replaces the whole html content instead of just adding lang=en to html.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    alert("It's loaded!")
    const cond = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]|| false;
    console.log(cond)
     if (cond) {
          $('html').each(function() {
              $(this).replaceWith($('<html lang="en">'));
          });
    }});
```

Also I tried below code but it doesn't work too, basically it gets html content and it appends with new html tag and content.

```
const htmlContent = $( "html" ).html();
    if (cond) {
        $('html').replaceWith('<html lang="en">' + htmlContent +  '</html>');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the optimal way of doing that because it could cause events to be detached or other performance issues. It would be safer to do:

```js
$('html').attr('lang', 'en')`
```

This way you are only adding an attribute, nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

The possible solution using vanilla JS might be.

```
document.querySelector('html').setAttribute("lang", "en")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `attr` method.

```
$(this).attr("lang", "en");
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code, you can try with vanilla js:

```
<script>
let domHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
let lang = domHTML.getAttribute('lang');
console.log('lang: ' + lang);
domHTML.setAttribute('lang', 'fr');
lang = domHTML.getAttribute('lang');
console.log('lang: ' + lang);
</script>
```

See details about [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) about using this attribute methods.